# no module error in angular with requirejs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs

I am trying to integrate angularjs with requirejs . How ever I am getting the error

`Uncaught Error: No module: app`

This is my setup

**main.coffee**

```
require.config
baseUrl : "/Scripts/"
paths :
    jquery : 'libs/jquery/jquery-2.0.3'
    angular : 'libs/angular/angular'
    'angular-resource' : 'libs/angular/angular-resource'
    bootstrap : 'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap'
shim :
    angular :
        exports :'angular'
    'angular-resource':
        deps :['angular']
    jquery :
        exports: ['jquery']
    bootstrap : 
        deps :['jquery']
    app:
        deps :['app-boot']
require ['app-angular/modules/app','app-angular/modules/app-boot'], ($,angular)->
```

**app-boot.coffee**

```
require ['jquery','angular','bootstrap'], ($,angular)->
$(document).ready ->
    angular.bootstrap document,['app']
```

**app.coffee**

```
define "app",['angular','angular-resource'], (angular)->    
angular.module 'app',['ngResource']
```

**StudentController.coffee**

```
require ["app"] , (app) ->
app.controller "StudentController" , ($scope) ->
    $scope.msg = "Hello Joy !! How are you !! You are in Angularjs"
```

And my Index.cshtml

```
<div class="page-content">
<div ng-controller="StudentController">
    <p ng-bind="{{msg}}">
    </p>
</div>
```

However it gives the error `Uncaught Error: No module: app`

I also removed the `ng-app` from html also have bootstrapped the angular manually on domready . So where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to invert the dependency on this bit of code:

```
app:
    deps :['app-boot']
```

It's the way around:

```
'app-boot': {
    deps: ['app']
 }
```

Your `app-boot.coffee` file depends on the module `app` that is defined on the `app.coffee` file

Comment: So you mean to say first the module has to be initiated and then the application needs to be bootstrapped ???

Comment: Yes, I believe so. 
On your code, first this needs to happen `var app = angular.module("app", [], function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) { // your code here });` and then you can do this `angular.bootstrap(document,["app"]);` - I know I wrote it in pure JavaScript rather than CoffeScript, but I am sure you will understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're following this [guide](http://kielczewski.eu/2013/04/integrating-angularjs-with-requirejs/), which is double plus good.

I was able to get it to work but kept getting the same error message because in my Angular controller, 'app' was not defined.  It appears the 'app.controller' doesn't get set there, as the guide states, and just loading it via the 'require' statement is sufficient.':

`require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'users', 'angular', 'directives', 'app']`

This is only a little different than yours.

```
/* shim */
require.config({
 shim: {
    underscore: {
        exports: '_'
    },
    backbone: {
        deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
        exports: "Backbone"
    },
    "angular":{
        exports:"angular"
    },
    "directives":{/* this is my custom Angular directive */
        deps:["angular"]
    }
}
});

/* RequireJS module */
define("app", ["angular", "directives"], function(angular)
{
    var app = angular.module("app", ["zipppyModule"]);

    angular.element(document).ready(function()
        { angular.bootstrap(document,['zippyModule']); });
});

/* 'app' loads the module */
require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'users', 'angular', 'directives', 'app']
```

Comment: Yes true , you can just load your context of required scripts just through require statement and passing through the module names . However i did a different approach . I made `deps:['app/app']` in the main.js which actually contains all the required modules . There can multiple ways to achieve this . Since requirejs modules are so flexible you can use it in a various ways